# finding the Equivalence class and Quotient set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$A$ is the group of all points, we define the next relations(T):
$$ P\;T\;Q\iff |P|=|Q|$$ wheres $|P|$ is the distance from the begining (0,0).

> a. what is the relations Equivalence class?
>
> b. what is the Quotient set?

Here is what I done:
a.$$\forall(a,b),(c,d)\in RxR:(a,b)R(a,b)\iff \sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{c^2+d^2} $$
is that what I needed to do? or I didn't understood it correct?
b. I don't even mean what is quotient set (I need to be with all the qounient sets possibles? please explain me what I'm wrong at and how to do it correct....
Thanks!

Comment: What you have done isn't wrong, but... I think if you don't focus so much on the _coordinates_ of points and rather look at the _geometry_ of the problem. For instance, what does the equivalence class containing $(1,0)$ _look_ like, as a drawing?

Comment: it contains all the circles with radius of 1.... is that what you mean? and if so is that what i need to define? and how?

Comment: Not "all the circles with radius $1$", but "all the points on the circle centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $1$". That is one equivalence class. Can you think of another equivalence class? For instance, what about the equivalence class containing $(3,4)$?

Comment: yes I understand the point. its all the point at the circle that centered at $(0,0)$  and his radius is $\sqrt{9+16} =5$.. but i dont understand how can i write is as a correct answer...?
you think that i need to write all the circles with the radius equal to $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} $ ?

Comment: No, just "An equivalence class is a circle centered around the origin", except that $(0,0)$ also belongs to an equivalence class, all alone by itself. It's up to you how you decide to phrase it. It could be "An equivalence class is a set of the form $\{P \in \Bbb R^2\mid |P| = x\}$ for some $x \geq 0$."

Comment: and if so what is the Quotient set?  is it RxR?

Comment: Can you think of a very simple way do describe the _difference_ between the equivalence classes? What distinguishes one equivalence class from another?

Comment: The Diffrence is R , its diffrent in each one....

Comment: Exactly. So the quotient space is the set of different possible radii, namely $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31865/discussion-between-user152711-and-arthur).

Comment: @Arthur thank you so much!!!